# Saving Django model throws OperationalError: cannot start a transaction within a transaction

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-unittest

I'm seeing a weird error in a Django unittest where, on rare occasions, attempting to save a model instance will throw the exception:

```
OperationalError: cannot start a transaction within a transaction
```

What would cause this?

The really odd thing is that this is happening in a loop like:

```
for i in range(10):
    obj = MyModel(name='blah %i' % i)
    obj.save()
```

and it'll get through several iterations before throwing the exception.

Since it's non-deterministic, it's incredibly frustrating to diagnose, and I have no clear idea what's happening. Since I'm using Django's standard TransactionTestCase, I would have thought this error was impossible, since the TestCase wraps each test in an `atomic()` context manager to wrap all changes in a transaction. There should be nothing attempting to create another transaction.

The only other thing I could think might effect this is that my model has a post_save signal handler, and that that might be someone breaking outside of the transaction, or otherwise interfering, but I'm not sure how to test it, since I can't reliably reproduce the error.